# Set tag and hidden for objects on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tags, hidden

I am re-using Apple's [AdvancedTableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html) example to create a custom, fast-scrolling tableview.  Specifically, I am using their `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell` method which draws the content on the tableviewcell with `drawRect`

Everything works, but how do you hide a label or set the tag for a label or image using their method?  Doing it this way is pretty new to me (without IB), so I apologize ahead of time if it's something easy.

The code that sets the cell content is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

[_cell.animalIcon drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5.0, 5.0)];

[_cell.animalName drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(93.0, 25.0)];

_highlighted ? [[UIColor whiteColor] set] : [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.23 alpha:1.0] set];
[_cell.animalDescription drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 54.0) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];

[_cell.animalNameString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(93.0, 5.0) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag` and `hidden` are properties of `UIView`. Since you are not dealing with instances of UIView anymore (you don't have UILabels or UIImageViews, just NSStrings or UIImages), they don't have a `tag` property.  If you want to hide a specific part of text, just don't draw it in `drawRect:`. Use a simple if statement to test for whatever condition you need to determine whether the text should be drawn or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The problem lies in me using the tag property to decide which view controller to push based on the value of `animalNameString` ...Is there another way I can do that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?